# Subscript access when value may be null

Tags: flutter, dart, list-comprehension

```dart
Text(
  dataList[index]["merchant"]["merchant"] ?? "No Merchant",
  maxLines: 1,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  style: const TextStyle(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      color: Colors.black),
),
```

What is the best way to do list comprehension when your text might be null. I don't want to add a ton of if, else blocks. The issue is that when `dataList[index]["merchant"]` is null, the flutter engine errors out because there is no corresponding subscript. The `??` operator also doesn't work because the flutter engine errors out before it can display the no merchant value.

When `dataList[index]["merchant"]` is null instead of populated, the error looks like so:

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
```

Comment: You can do `dataList[index]?["merchant"]?["merchant"] ?? "No Merchant"`

Comment: Can you also give an example of the possible valid value for `dataList`?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan It hangs at the same spot

Comment: @DhafinRayhan heres the relevant data fields: [{receiptid: ..., merchant: [{"merchant": ""}], project: [{"project": ""}]}, ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the JSON data that you give above, it seems like the structure is: List > "merchant" > List > "merchant". To access that, you can use this:

```dart
(dataList[index1]["merchant"] as List)[index2]["merchant"]
```

Replace `index1` and `index2` with the appropriate values. Make sure they don't exceed their corresponding list size.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. I forgot that merchant's is a list. Thank you